# Firefox drag and drop URL

Tags: firefox, drag-and-drop

can any one help me with this problem of firefox?

I have two firefox windows open. Now i want to drag a URL link from one window to the another, but I can't do it in Ubuntu 12.04

I can do this easily in windows. I cannot switch to the other window when I click and hold a link to be dropped...

Anyone experience the same problem and have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have both Firefox windows open side by side, and click on the Tab that you want moved, and drag it to the new windows.

or

Click on the little icon to the left of a URL, and drag it to the new window.

or

Right click on the Tab that you want moved, and click on Move to a New Window.

[image]